# Looking for an iOS news aggregator that doesn't hide links to actual article source

Tags: ios, rss, reading

I am trying to find an alternative news reader to [News360](http://news360.com), [News Republic](http://news-republic.com), or [Flipboard](http://flipboard.com). Those apps all have the content layout, interface, and filtering that I want, but do not provide an easy access to the source feed's article link.

All the aforementioned apps hide the source link, either by making it hard to find or by replacing it with their own 'permalink' and, unfortunately, this breaks the functionality of many other apps. For example, if I am reading an article, using News Republic, and want to quickly save it for reading later or clip part of the content (while still having a reference to the source) with an app like Pinboard, News Republic provides a link which is **useable only by their app or service**, resulting in a Pinboard entry that just contains an obfuscated link. Its a bit like forcing a "provided by News Republic" credit on every share/copy, but without any actual content included.

So, are there any apps, like the above, but that actually provide the **real** link to the source article to other iOS widgets/plugins?